# Parallel Output from R Loop

Tags: r

I am running this for loop in R and it would give me a big matrix output, which will not hold in to my system memory. Basically my data is text and finding the distance between each row like R1 has to find distance of R2, R3 so on I am trying to loop it for all the observations. Hence I am planning it to bring parallel output from loop and save these results offline from R for each loop. I am beginner in R and I would much appreciate your help on this.

No.of Obs - 300726
Variables - 4 
Resulting Observations - 90Crores

```
    library(miscTools);library(plyr);library(reshape);library(gtools);library(matlab);
library(stringdist);library(SimilarityMeasures);library(gplots);library(manipulate);library(matrixcalc);

Customer=read.table("Consolidated_Rndm_Added.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Customer$Createdid=paste0("C",row.names(Customer))

base_data=subset(Customer,select=c(ADHAR_CARD,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,STREET,Createdid))
names_temp=base_data$Createdid
Createdid_Actual=subset(Customer,select=c(Createdid,CUSTOMER_ID))

names_base_data=names(base_data)
names_base_data=names_base_data[names_base_data != "Createdid"]
FC_LCS_stringdist=data.frame()

ch=as.data.frame(names_temp)
rm(Customer)

for(k in 1:(length(names_base_data)))

{
  selec_var=names_base_data[k]
  present_base_data=subset(base_data,select=c(selec_var))
  present_refer_data=subset(base_data,select=c(selec_var,"Createdid"))
  present_refer_data$trnw=row.names(present_refer_data)
  present_refer_data$trnw=as.numeric(present_refer_data$trnw)
  present_refer_data$decile<-ceil(present_refer_data$trnw/100)

  spli_ref=unique(present_refer_data$decile)
  Consolidated_LCS_stringdist=data.frame()

  present_base_data1=as.matrix(present_base_data)
  for(tk in 1:length(spli_ref))

  {
    present_refer_data2=subset(present_refer_data, decile %in% tk)
    present_refer_data2=subset(present_refer_data2,select=c(selec_var,"Createdid"))
    names_temp_ref=present_refer_data2$Createdid
    present_refer_data2=subset(present_refer_data2,select=c(selec_var))
    present_refer_data2=as.data.frame(present_refer_data2)

    present_refer_data1=as.matrix(present_refer_data2)
    class(present_refer_data1)

    LCS_stringdist=stringdistmatrix(present_base_data1,present_refer_data1,method="lcs")

    LCS_stringdist=as.data.frame(LCS_stringdist)
    names(LCS_stringdist)=names_temp_ref
    LCS_stringdist=cbind(ch,LCS_stringdist)
    LCS_stringdist=melt(LCS_stringdist,id=c("names_temp"))
    LCS_stringdist$var_name=selec_var
    LCS_stringdist=rename(LCS_stringdist, replace = c("names_temp" = "Referid","variable"="baseid"))

    Consolidated_LCS_stringdist=smartbind(Consolidated_LCS_stringdist,LCS_stringdist)
    rm(LCS_stringdist,present_refer_data2)
  }

  FC_LCS_stringdist=smartbind(FC_LCS_stringdist,Consolidated_LCS_stringdist)

  rm(Consolidated_LCS_stringdist)
  print(selec_var)
}
FC_LCS_stringdist =cast(FC_LCS_stringdist, baseid+Referid ~ var_name, sum, value = 'value',margins=T)
write.csv(FC_LCS_stringdist,"FC_LCS_stringdist.csv")
```

Comment: If your question is about writing files locally after each loop iteration, all your intermediate code steps are not important here. Please narrow down/edit your question if so and provide a minimum working example if there is another problem. I assume that you find a good answer how to do so using the search function.

Comment: Yes, I would like to write files locally after each loop iteration